# Julia: Making empty/initialized multidimensional arrays of self defined types

Tags: multidimensional-array, initialization, julia, composite-types, type-constructor

I am making a type of my own called `KeyVal` defined as below:

```
type KeyVal
    first::Int
    second::Float64
end
```

And I am trying to make an empty/or initialized at zero matrix that its elements are of type `KeyVal`.
Normally with other types I do

```
myMat = zeros(KeyVal, (10,3))
```

But this will not work, because there is no `zeros` defined for this composite type. So I try to define my own zeros function in the following way:

```
import Base.zeros

function zeros(KeyVal,dims)
    if length(dims) > 1
        n=dims[1]
        m=dims[2]
        temp = repeat([KeyVal(0,0.0)], outer=m*n)
        temp = reshape(temp, (n,m))
        return temp
    elseif length(dims) == 1
        n=dims[1]
        temp= repeat([KeyVal(0,0.0)], outer=n)
        temp = reshape(temp, (n))
        return temp
    end
end
```

This adds to the methods list of other previously defined `zeros`.
But using it will generate errors:

```
myMat = zeros(KeyVal, (N,M))

MethodError: no method matching zero(::Type{KeyVal})
Closest candidates are:
    .....
```

I am wondering whether I can resolve this in a way or maybe signal this in the type constructor so that any data structure that involves the type `KeyVal` is initialized at (first = 0, second=0.0).

Previously I tried defining the matrix as :

```
myMat2 = Array{KeyVal,(N,M)}
```

This will create the matrix except all its elements are `#undef`, and in this case I cannot access any of the elements of the `myMat2`:

```
myMat2[1,1]
UndefRefError: access to undefined reference
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an uninitialized array of any type `T` and dimension `N` with

```
Array{T, N}(undef, dims...)
```

In the special case of one and two dimensional arrays, you can use the aliases `Vector` and `Matrix`, e.g.,

```
julia> m = Matrix{KeyVal}(undef, 2,2)
2×2 Array{KeyVal,2}:
 #undef  #undef
 #undef  #undef
```

You can then set the elements as usual, e.g.,

```
m[1,2] = KeyVal(1,2)
```

If it makes sense for your type to implement a `zero` method, you can define

```
Base.zero(::Type{KeyVal}) = KeyVal(0,0)
```

and `zeros` will work correctly

```
julia> zeros(KeyVal, (2,2))
2×2 Array{KeyVal,2}:
 KeyVal(0,0.0)  KeyVal(0,0.0)
 KeyVal(0,0.0)  KeyVal(0,0.0)
```

**Warning:**

`zeros` uses `fill!` which fills the array with copies of the same instance. Instead, use the comprehension below or an immutable type that doesn't contain references (`isbits` is true). The latter approach is likely faster as well because the array can be stored as one continuous block of memory. In that case, you can also use `fill(KeyVal(0,0), dims..)` directly instead of defining `zero`. On 0.6, the new `struct` keyword creates an immutable type by default.

**Edit:**

Another possibility is to use a comprehension

```
julia> m = [KeyVal() for i=1:3, j=1:2]
3×2 Array{KeyVal,2}:
 KeyVal(0,0.0)  KeyVal(0,0.0)
 KeyVal(0,0.0)  KeyVal(0,0.0)
 KeyVal(0,0.0)  KeyVal(0,0.0)
```

For convenience, I previously defined the outer constructor

```
KeyVal() = KeyVal(0,0)
```

Comment: Thanks, interestingly running `m[1,2]` alone gives me an error, but ` = KeyVal(1,2)` works perfectly fine, but the zero extension is the most convenient solution.

Comment: The error prevents the access to an undefined reference. Note that for an `immutable` type, no error will be thrown and the unitialized matrix will be filled with random values instead.

Comment: Yet there is a problem with the zeros() approach, as there is only one instance made, if I want to change the values of a m[i,j] this will change all the instances elsewhere as well.

Comment: @A.Yazdiha You are right! `zeros` is implemented using `fill!` which fills the array with the same instance. Use the comprehension from my edit or an immutable type instead. The latter approach probably has a higher performance as well.